# Unable to define and use heleper function value as global variable in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to showing notification in my project so thats why i am creating helperFunction and call in main server.js file and define as global variable but when it return value [object promise],If i call helper function in my other controller it return value but as global variable it return object promise

```
************ helper function *************

const fs = require('fs');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;
const models = require(appRoot + '/models');

const helpersService = () => {
 const getNotification = async () => {
        
        var findStatus = 0;

        if (findStatus != '' && findStatus != null) {
            var whereOptions = {
                is_read: {
                    [Op.iLike]: '%' + findStatus + '%'
                }
            }
        } else {
            var whereOptions = {}
        }

        let getNotifications = await models.Notifications.findAll({
            include: [{
                attributes: ['id', 'full_name', 'email'],
                model: models.Users,
                as: 'user'
            }],
            where: whereOptions,
            raw: true,
        });

        
        return getNotifications;


    };

    return {
        getTranslatedText,
        notificationStatus,
        getNotification,
    };
};

module.exports = helpersService;

**************************************

*************** server.js *************

global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);
const helpersService = require(appRoot + '/services/helpers.service');
global.notifcations = helpersService().getNotification();

****************************************

**************view.ejs*******************

 <li style="padding-top: 0px; border-top: none;">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/users/logout">
        <%= notifcations %></a></li>

***************************************

*********** output is *****************

[object promise`]`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At fitst you must add await to your function

```
global.notifcations = await helpersService().getNotification();
```

And then your notifications is an array of object and you can't see this directly, use this method

```
for Example notifications[0].name
```

Comment: got this error SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
.............

Comment: (async () => global.notifcations = await helpersService().getNotification() )();

Answer (score 1):

You are actually calling your getNotification function and setting the return value to the the globals object, thats why it says [object Promise].

You shlould pass only the function:

```
global.notifcations = helpersService().getNotification;
```

Comment: it return my helper function text not that value output like async const getNotification = async () => { var findStatus = 0 ; ............................

Comment: if you want the return value, you should use await, because getNotifications is an async function and right now you are not waiting for the returned promise to resolve.
global.notifcations = await helpersService().getNotification();